# 2013 Honda Accord 3.5L v6 steering problem

Tags: honda, accord, power-steering

I have for the past few months been having an issue with my 2013 Accord steering. It from time to time while driving and parked will start to turn to the right and or left but mostly to the right by itself with some force. I took it into the honda dealer and they did the recall for the power steering but after I got it back and drove it for abit the issue came back. I'm not sure what the issue can be but I'm sure it's not alignment or the tires as I've changed the tires and rims and balanced them properly at a shop. Please let me know if anyone else has this issue or if you know what might be wrong with it. The issue comes and goes but is scary when driving and all of a sudden it turns to the right with force.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score -1):

I am curious, did the dealer do the software update, and the problem kept happening? I believe the only real fix is replacing to EPS gearbox assembly which is a $3,000 repair.
This is a known problem with 2013-2014 Honda Accords. The NHTSA has issued an investigation into this, search for Honda Accord loss of steering control. If you have not already reported this to the NHTSA, I suggest you do that. It appears that power steering assist activates without warning, without driver input, and usually without error codes. It is a very dangerous condition.